# Calling getter from imported class

Tags: java

I am having trouble calling a getter from an imported class.
I have created a working class (Students) and an action class (ProgressReport).  The main class reads a text file and writes the data to an array.  The data is then manipulated in the working class.  Last, ProgressReport.generateReport will create a report giving the students name, their grade average and the letter grade associate with that average.
I am having trouble using the Students getters from the Progress Report class.  Eclipse is saying the method is undefined.  I am not exactly sure what I have done wrong or how to go about fixing it.  Any help would be very much appreciated.
NOTE: I added some println to make sure parts of the code were being executed.
  Thank you all in advance.

Code to follow:

Progress Report

```
package Lab1A;

import java.util.*;

import Lab1A.Students;

import java.io.*; 

public class ProgressReport {
public Students section[][];

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
      Students tmpStudent;

      ProgressReport progressReport = new ProgressReport();

      progressReport.readInputFile();
      progressReport.generateReport();


      System.out.println("\nSEARCH TEST");
      tmpStudent = null;
      tmpStudent = progressReport.sequentialSearch(0, "Cooper");
      if (tmpStudent != null) 
          System.out.println("Found " + tmpStudent.getName() +
                  "\tAverage = " + tmpStudent.getAverage() +
                  "\tGrade = " + tmpStudent.getGrade());
      else System.out.println("Fail to find the student");

      tmpStudent = null;
      tmpStudent = progressReport.sequentialSearch(0, "Bronson");
      if (tmpStudent != null) 
          System.out.println("Found " + tmpStudent.getName() +
                  "\tAverage = " + tmpStudent.getAverage() +
                  "\tGrade = " + tmpStudent.getGrade());
      else System.out.println("Fail to find the student");

      tmpStudent = null;
      tmpStudent = progressReport.sequentialSearch(1, "Diana");
      if (tmpStudent != null) 
          System.out.println("Found " + tmpStudent.getName() +
                  "\tAverage = " + tmpStudent.getAverage() +
                  "\tGrade = " + tmpStudent.getGrade());
      else System.out.println("Fail to find the student");

  }

  public ProgressReport()
  {
      section = new Students [2][];
  }

  public void readInputFile() throws FileNotFoundException
  {
      System.out.println("in readInputFile method");
      //Open file
      File input = new File("Lab1A.in");
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(input);
      System.out.println("file is open");
      //Read file data
      int currentStudent = 0;
      while (inputFile.hasNext())
      {
          System.out.println("In while loop");
          //Get Student count
          int rows = inputFile.nextInt();

          //Read student data
          section[currentStudent] = new Students[rows];
          System.out.println("array initiated");
          for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
          {  
              System.out.println("In for loop");
              //read in a students info
              String sName = inputFile.next();

              //Read in grades
              int grade1 = inputFile.nextInt();
              int grade2 = inputFile.nextInt();
              int grade3 = inputFile.nextInt();
              int grade4 = inputFile.nextInt();
              int grade5 = inputFile.nextInt();

              //Send to Students Array
              section[currentStudent][i] = new Students(sName, grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5);


          }
          //Next Student Line
          currentStudent++;           

      }
      inputFile.close();
  }

  public void generateReport()
  {
      System.out.println("Progress Report");
      double average = Students.class.getAverage();
      //String section = "Section\n";




  }

  public Students sequentialSearch(int section, String searchName)
  {
    return null;


  }
}
```

Students Class

```
package Lab1A;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Students {

    private String name;
    private char grade;
    private double average;
    private int scores[];

    public Students(String sName, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3, int grade4, int grade5)
    {
        //CONSTRUCTOR load data from ProgressReport
        name = sName;
        int newScores[] = {grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5};
        scores = newScores;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public char getGrade() {
        if(average  >= 90 && average <= 100)
        {
            grade = 'A';
        }
        if(average  >= 80 && average < 90)
        {
            grade = 'B';
        }
        if(average  >= 70 && average < 80)
        {
            grade = 'C';
        }
        if(average  >= 60 && average < 70)
        {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        if(average  >= 0 && average < 60)
        {
            grade = 'F';
        }

        return grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(char grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }
    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }
    public int[] getScores() {
        return scores;
    }
    public void setScores(int[] scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }



    //Calculate average score
    public void calculateAverage()
    {
        int total = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
                    {
                    total += scores[i];
                    }
                average = total*1.0/scores.length;
    }

    //calculate letter grade based on average score (calulateAverage.average)
    public void calculateGrade()
    {

        if(average  >= 90 && average <= 100)
        {
            grade = 'A';
        }
        if(average  >= 80 && average < 90)
        {
            grade = 'B';
        }
        if(average  >= 70 && average < 80)
        {
            grade = 'C';
        }
        if(average  >= 60 && average < 70)
        {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        if(average  >= 0 && average < 60)
        {
            grade = 'F';
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Which line in your code is producing the error?  Consider that when asking volunteers to help you it is polite to provide all the necessary information and make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: I assume you are referring to  `double average = Students.class.getAverage();`  I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen here.  `getAverage()` is an instance method, and requires an instance on which to operate.  The expression `Students.class` returns the `Class<>` object for the `Students` class, which is not an instance of `Students`.  You are going to have to clarify the question.

Comment: I think that Josh is trying to calculate the average among all student objects, in which case he would need to iterate over each student, calling Student#getAverage() and adding to an accumulator variable, then dividing by the number of students (casting to double too)....but I am not sure whether this is the only problem.

Comment: I'm really confused as to this line:  public Students section[][].  I understand Students[][] section, but what does the former do??  I've never seen that before.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not put enough detail.  I am new to java with no formal education.  I am still learning some of the convention.  Thank you all for the help.  The problem at hand was solved by the below comment but it looks like a have a few more hurdles now.  Thank you all again.  This is all very encouraging!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not specifying which Student you want the average of (Not sure why you named your class students with an s).  It needs to look something like this:

```
section[1][1].getAverage()
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks.  (I am new to Java and don't know all of the conventions as of yet.